# How do I make a container offset to the left at a particular point and fill the remaining space in CSS?

Tags: html, css

For example, `.container-a` has these styles:

```
.container-a {
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This means that `.container-a` will never exceed the defined width of 1240px. The left and right auto margins mean the browser automatically calculates equal margins on the left and right side which makes it always centered no matter how large the screen gets.

Now, say I want to have another container. This `container-b` should offset the same left margin that `.container-a` offsets to the left which means both `.container-a` and `.container-b` start at the same point. The only difference is that this particular `container-b` doesn't offset a right margin and does not have a defined maximum width which means it fills the remaining available space on the browser window irrespective of how large the screen gets. Is that possible and how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of absolute positioning as suggested in the other answers, I would go with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) here, which allows you to do some basic math in CSS. (Absolute positioning is not a tool for basic layouting, and can lead to a lot of other issues with the rest of the document flow.)

The trick is to simply divide the available window width (100%) in half, subtract half of the max-width of container a - and then set that as margin-left for container b.

I went with a smaller max-width of 500px here, so that the effect is easily visible here in the rendered snippet, but you can easily modify this accordingly, for the max-width you actually need.

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
}

.container-a {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.container-b {
  margin: 1em auto;
  margin-left: calc(100% / 2 - 250px) /* 250px = half the max-width of container a */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-a">
  I am container-a
</div>
<div class="container-b">
  I am container-b
</div>
```

You might want to wrap this into a media query, so that it doesn’t misbehave when the available window width is smaller than the max-width (because that would result in a *negative* margin-left for container b here.)

Comment: P.s., this could of course also be written as `calc((100% - 500px) / 2)`, which perhaps makes even a bit more sense here, because then you have the same number `500px` in both places, as the max-width for container a, and here. Makes it a little easier to spot that those two are related, if the max-width ever needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
<div class='c'>
  <div class='c1'>container</div>
  <div class='c2'>container</div>
</div>

.c {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.c1 {

  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.c2 {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but this doesn't fill the available space in the window. It only sets the width to 100% of the parent `.c` which is `400px`.